# Name this typeError? Probably scope error

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

WARNING: Probably not a typeError. Doing scripting algorithms for fun. Trying to learn something/sharpen problem solving => I commented out the undefined array. I can't tell why it's throwing an error.

```js
function arrayManipulation(n, queries) {

  var array = new Array(n).fill(0)
  var x = 0
  var recurring = (argmnt, query, y) => {
        
    //problem start here
    var start = query[0],
    end = query[1]
    //problem end somewhere else

    var newArg = argmnt.map((el, index) =>{
      if(index+1 >= start && index+1 <= end){
        return query[2] + el
      }else{
        return el
      }
    })
    console.log(newArg)
    if ( y < queries.length ){
      y += 1
      recurring(newArg, queries[y], y)
    }else{
      return newArg
    }
  }
        
  var solution = recurring(array, queries[x], x)       
}
    
arrayManipulation(5, [[1, 2, 100], [2, 5, 100], [3, 4, 100]])
```

Although the script runs fine and give me the desired output. It throws a stderr in node or typeerror in JS. I just want to know why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `y` variable. In your check `y < queries.length` you *first* check for the length and *then* increment.

If your array has a length of `3` (as it does in your example), you will check if `y` is less than `3` and if it’s `2`, it passes the test, gets incremented to `3` and then you pass `queries[3]` to the next `recurring()` invocation. The last element of `queries` is `queries[2]`, though. So `queries[3]` is `undefined` and inside the function, you try `query[0]` which is accessing property `0` of `undefined`. That’s the error.

```js
function arrayManipulation(n, queries) {

    var array = new Array(n).fill(0)
    var x = 0
    var recurring = (argmnt, query, y) => {

    //problem start here
        var start = query[0],
            end = query[1]
    //problem end somewhere else

        var newArg = argmnt.map((el, index) =>{
            if(index+1 >= start && index+1 <= end){
                return query[2] + el
            }else{
                return el
            }
        })
        console.log(newArg)
        y += 1 // now is here
        if ( y < queries.length ){

            // was here
            recurring(newArg, queries[y], y)
        }else{
            return newArg
        }
    }
    var solution = recurring(array, queries[x], x)

}

arrayManipulation(5, [[1, 2, 100],
[2, 5, 100],
[3, 4, 100]])
```

You have two choices: either increment first and then do the check (as in the snippet above), or check for `queries.length - 1`, like this:

```
if ( y < queries.length - 1 ){
```

---

Also, a bit of an optimization. You don’t need the `y` variable. It’s basically just `x` but passed along as an argument. You have access to `x` from `recurring()` so you might as well use *it*:

```js
function arrayManipulation(n, queries) {

  var array = new Array(n).fill(0)
  var x = 0
  var recurring = (argmnt, query) => {

    //problem start here
    var start = query[0],
      end = query[1]
    //problem end somewhere else

    var newArg = argmnt.map((el, index) => {
      if (index + 1 >= start && index + 1 <= end) {
        return query[2] + el
      } else {
        return el
      }
    })
    console.log(newArg)
    x += 1
    if (x < queries.length) {
      recurring(newArg, queries[x], x)
    } else {
      return newArg
    }
  }

  var solution = recurring(array, queries[x])
}

arrayManipulation(5, [
  [1, 2, 100],
  [2, 5, 100],
  [3, 4, 100]
])
```

Comment: yea, I was tinkering around with it trying to get it to work. I was being misdirected! But Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got from your script:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 22
}
```

This is normal because of this part:

```
if ( y < queries.length ){
      y += 1
      recurring(newArg, queries[y], y)
```

You have `3` queries. At one point, `y` will equal `2`.

It will be incremented and will equal `3`.
`queries[3]` doesn't exist and will be `undefined`. (because, you do know that an array's first index is 0, do you?)

Then, in the next `recurring`, you'll call `query[0]` on it, but it is `undefined`: it will crash.

That's all ;) You `if` condition is not good ;)

It must be `if ( y < queries.length - 1 )`